# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

highlight the error in this part of fullcalendar/main.js code

```
function addDefs(defs) {
    for (var _i = 0, defs_1 = defs; _i < defs_1.length; _i++)
```

this is my code:

```
yarn add @fullcalendar/core
yarn add @fullcalendar/daygrid
```

application.js

```
import moment from 'moment'
window.moment = moment
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core/';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
global.FullCalendar = require("@fullcalendar/core/");
```

application.scss

```
@import '@fullcalendar/common/main.css';
@import '@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
```

view

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

        ....
    }
});

  // render the calendar
  calendar.render();
});
</script>
```

Comment: where you set the value of defs ??

Comment: Your setup code looks wrong. The `global.FullCalendar...` line shouldn't be necessary. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, here are my imports

```
import * as Calendar from '@fullcalendar/core';
import * as dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import * as listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import * as interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

window.FullCalendar = Calendar;
window.dayGridPlugin = dayGridPlugin;
window.listPlugin = listPlugin;
window.interactionPlugin = interactionPlugin;
```

and I'm using it like this :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                                let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

                                let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                                    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin ],
                                    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                                    initialDate: '2020-10-07',
                                    headerToolbar: {
                                        left: 'prev,next today',
                                        center: 'title',
                                        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                                    },
                                    events: [
                                        {
                                            title: 'All Day Event',
                                            start: '2020-10-01'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            title: 'Long Event',
                                            start: '2020-10-07',
                                            end: '2020-10-10'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            groupId: '999',
                                            title: 'Repeating Event',
                                            start: '2020-10-09T16:00:00'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            groupId: '999',
                                            title: 'Repeating Event',
                                            start: '2020-10-16T16:00:00'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            title: 'Conference',
                                            start: '2020-10-11',
                                            end: '2020-10-13'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            title: 'Meeting',
                                            start: '2020-10-12T10:30:00',
                                            end: '2020-10-12T12:30:00'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            title: 'Lunch',
                                            start: '2020-10-12T12:00:00'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            title: 'Meeting',
                                            start: '2020-10-12T14:30:00'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            title: 'Birthday Party',
                                            start: '2020-10-13T07:00:00'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            title: 'Click for Google',
                                            url: 'http://google.com/',
                                            start: '2020-10-28'
                                        }
                                    ]
                                });

                                calendar.render();
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [webpack lazy-loading](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/) to `import` [fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/daygrid-view).

```
const dayGridPlugin = await import('@fullcalendar/daygrid');
```

First, I got the same error. But then the webpack documentation gave me a hint:

> Note that when using import() on ES6 modules you must reference the `.default`
> property as it's the actual module object that will be returned when the promise
> is resolved.

So I solved this problem using `.default` property

```
const dayGridPlugin = (await import('@fullcalendar/daygrid')).default;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is there because `calendarEl` is null. Declare `calendar` before that function. After the line where you define `calendarEl`, wrap everything in the conditional check

```
var calendar;
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  if (calendarEl != null) {
     calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

        ....
     }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when introducing Webpack to already working application which worked with some older version of Fullcalendar. Some name of options of the library from npm have changed so I had to update them (like "defaultView" to "initialView"). And what caused the above-mentioned error was line:

```
plugins: ["interaction", "dayGrid", "timeGrid", "list"],
```

which I had to change to:

```
plugins: [interaction, dayGrid, timeGrid, list],
```